# Direction on OS Meridian data

Tags: ordnance-survey, os-opendata

I've been looking to use the Ordanance Survey's Meridian data (part of the their OpenData suite) for doing vehicle routing.

Whilst I can infer road class from the NUMBER property on each polyline, I cannot see anything that indicates if a polyline is unidirectional, or bidrectional. Am I just being unable to see this, or is this encoded somewhere else?

Comment: I suspect that OS reserved that information to a paid product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major Issue with Meridian 2 Data from Ordnance Survey (in OpenData format):

*Motorways, major and minor roads are represented in the data. **Complex junctions are collapsed to single 
nodes and multi-carriageways to single links**. To avoid congestion, some minor roads and cul-de-sacs less 
than 200 m are not represented in the minor road feature description of the data. Private roads and tracks are not present.*

Stated here
http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/meridian2/pdf/meridian2userguide.pdf

You can BUILD a Road Network (ArcGIS Network Analysis does an okay job)

But if you want full Network (Road Transport) capabilities you will be require **at cost**

Integrated Transport Network (ITN) Road Restriction Information (RRI) 
ITN RRI 
http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/osmastermap/layers/itn/

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/osmastermap/userguides/docs/ITNtechspec.pdf

Comment: Looking at that user guide, even the paid-for Meridian data wouldn't include it. Hadn't seen the ITN data, and might fit on a project that I'm working on for a client.

Comment: ITN is Expensive and not based on Tiles but Area. ITN with RRI is even more expensive. You might find TeleAtlas or Navteq data more fitting for you project at lower cost.